# Self Referencing problem in Rails active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a rails model called Task. And I use self-referencing design with my model

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Task"
  has_many :children, class_name: "Task",foreign_key: "parent_id"
end
```

So when I create my first object, It keep saying that "Parent must exist". I'm not sure how to make a object as a root in this hierarchy . Please help me with this

Comment: Show us the exception

Comment: I use the built-in errors.full_messages method of rails and when I create new task. I did not give it a parent_id so I got this kind of message "Parent must exist" from rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change from `belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Task"` to `belongs_to :parent, optional: true, class_name: "Task"`.

With that, you will be able to create a task without a parent. To validate if a task is a child or not you can check if parent_id has any value:

```rb
def child?
  parent_id.present?
end
```

Reference: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html